# How to handle the compensation event in bpmn?

Tags: bpmn, flowable

In the compensation event, can the compensation handler continue its course after the compensation is thrown, or should it wait for the two compensation processes to take place?

- In the figure below, after task 1, task 3 is executed and does not wait for the two compensation processes 1.1 and 2.2?
- Or after the implementation of compensation 1, task 3 is implemented and the two compensation processes 1.1 and 2.2 are canceled?
- Or the implementation of compensation 1, task 3 is not executed and the two compensation processes 1.1 and 2.2 are executed first and task 3 waits and after execution 1.1 and 2.2, task 3 is executed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5oQh.png)

Comment: I must admit, I am having difficulties understanding your problem. There are some inconsistencies in your description (you mean "compensation activities", not "processes"? the "compensation handler" is the activity that compensates another activity, not the compensation event; there is no "process 2.2"; you have two throwing compensation events but none of them have descriptions...etc.). It would be helpful to have the real-world example on which you are working (instead of "Task 1", "Task 2"...).

Comment: In general, a throwing compensation event is synchronous, i.e all the triggered compensation activities have to finish before the control flow continues